# To color the font

Tags: colors, fonts

Would like to highlight every record has "1/2" with yellow cell color and black font color. It is working fine to highlight the cell with yellow but not for the font. Here is the macro I am using:
any idea please to highlight the cell and the font for each cell modified

Comment: Here is the macro I am using: 
For Each rngCell In Range("F2:S1000") If ((Range("D2") Like "*Repair*") And Not (Range("B2") Like "*U19*")) Then If rngCell.Value Like "*1/2" Then rngCell.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 rngCell.Cells.Interior.Font.Color = vbBlack End If End If Next rngCell

Answer (score -1):

Your code is almost correct, but you're trying to change the font color in the wrong place. Specifically, you're trying to change the color of the font in the Interior of the cell, but Interior refers to the background of the cell, not the text. Thus, you should change the Font.Color of the rngCell directly, not its Interior.Font.Color.

Here's the corrected version of your macro:

```
For Each rngCell In Range("F2:S1000")
    If ((Range("D2") Like "Repair") And Not (Range("B2") Like "U19")) Then
        If rngCell.Value Like "*1/2*" Then
            rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            rngCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 
        End If
    End If
Next rngCell
```

Comment: I tried the new one but it doen't work and no cell higligted in yellow anymore, could you please double check. Here is sample data of what I am using:

Comment: Province Vendor Location Group Calendar Interval 21/05/2023 22/05/2023 23/05/2023 24/05/2023
ON U23-ON XYZ A-NI - DTH SFU Residential Repair AM  1/3  0/2  1/3  2/2
ON U23-ON   PM  0/5  0/2  4/4  2/2
ON U23-ON   EV 0/0 0/0  1/1  1/1
ON U23-ON   C/A  1/8  0/4  6/8  5/5
ON U23-ON  B-NI - DTH SFU Residential Install AM   0/2  0/2  1/2
ON U23-ON   PM   0/3  2/3  2/2
ON U23-ON   EV  0/0 0/0  1/1
ON U23-ON   C/A   0/5  2/5  4/5

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).